# Start and Finish Audio

Tags: c#, record, naudio

I started programming audio processing. My problem is to record and save to wav file. Currently I work fine when using "enter" to finish recording. But I want the sound to start when i say and end itself when I'm silent !! Is there any way please help me, please !!!
- Code :

```
class Program
{
    static WaveFileWriter wavefile;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Recording....");
        WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
        waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 1);
        waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
        string tempFile = (@"e:/Test/testrecord.wav");
        wavefile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);
        waveSource.StartRecording();
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to stop");
        Console.ReadLine();
        waveSource.StopRecording();
    }

    static void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        wavefile.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: think of it as a loop that keeps listening the sound, if it can't detect any within a specific time frame, it stops recording.

Comment: you can help to continue with code on?, thank! @ user5173426, i am beginner !